# are php and dotnet feasible together?

Tags: php, .net

can i make a project whose designing part is done in php and database connectivity in dot net?? Please help??

Answer (score 4):

**If by *database connectivity in dot net* you mean using MS SQL Server, then YES, it is possible.**

There is a library of functions beginning with [`mssql_connect()`](http://php.net/mssql_connect) that lets you establishes a connection to a MS SQL server and work on it through PHP.

Answer (score 2):

Possible, yes. Practical, no. Why do you need an extra layer when PHP can do everything with the PDO extension anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Why you'd want to add the extra overhead and bypass PHP's own database functions, I don't know, but you can always take a look at [PHP's DOTNET](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dotnet.php) class or [.Net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dotnet.php) extension

Answer (score 0):

yes. you can use plugin for php in visual stdio.. add "vs.php" plugin.. whch can be downloaded & instaled and use php & dot.net.

even Integrated Development Environment (IDE) helps you to write coding same as dotnet